# Jquery Clone multiple items on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

My Jquery clones element multiple times on a single click. Code at [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/mvug9zan/).

I want to clone element based on data attribute from menu list which reference to actual code from appName_list ID.

I'm trying to achieve single item on single click (further I can add multiple same items in multiple clicks).

Thanx in advance

```js
$(".appNameSelect").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('addNow');
    $('.addNow').on('click', function(e) {

      $("#appName_list .appName_main[data-id='" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "']").clone().appendTo("#appendTo");
      e.preventDefault();
    })
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('addNow');
  }
);
```

```css
#appName_list {
  display: none;
}

#appendTo {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appName_list">

  <div class="appName_main" data-type="header" data-id="1">
    Header Data
  </div>
  <div class="appName_main" data-type="header" data-id="2">
    Header Data Two
  </div>

  <div class="appName_main" data-type="footer" data-id="3">
    Footer Data
  </div>
  <div class="appName_main" data-type="header" data-id="4">
    Footer Data Two
  </div>

  <div class="appName_main" data-type="offers" data-id="5">
    Offers Data
  </div>
  <div class="appName_main" data-type="offers" data-id="6">
    Offers Data Two
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Menu_list">

  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="header" data-id="1">
    Header One
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="header" data-id="2">
    Header Two
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="footer" data-id="3">
    Footer One
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="footer" data-id="4">
    Footer Two
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="offers" data-id="5">
    Offers One
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="offers" data-id="6">
    Offers Two
  </div>

</div>

<div id="appendTo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is so due to you set up a new onclick handler each time you hover the ".appNameSelect" element.

As a possible solution I could suggest the following

```
$(".appNameSelect").hover(
  function() {

    // possible protection from click handler being bound twice
    if(this.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    this.isInitialized = true;

    $(this).addClass('addNow');
    $('.addNow').on('click', function(e) {
      $("#appName_list .appName_main[data-id='" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "']").clone().appendTo("#appendTo");
      e.preventDefault();
    })
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('addNow');
  }
);
```

Another option would be to unbind you handler via `.off` before `.on` binding, but the flag solution (`this.isInitialized`) is cheaper.

Comment: How can I improve this I added on hover because I dont wanted to add more code to it

Comment: I think it would be better to setup all click handlers right after the DOM is initialized.

Comment: @VickyParab If you don't want to change the logic I would suggest to protect click-handler binding from doing it twice... I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

off() your button click before on().

```js
$(".appNameSelect").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('addNow');
    $('.addNow').off().on('click', function(e) {

      $("#appName_list .appName_main[data-id='" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "']").clone().appendTo("#appendTo");
      e.preventDefault();
    })
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('addNow');
  }
);
```

```css
#appName_list {
  display: none;
}

#appendTo {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appName_list">

  <div class="appName_main" data-type="header" data-id="1">
    Header Data
  </div>
  <div class="appName_main" data-type="header" data-id="2">
    Header Data Two
  </div>

  <div class="appName_main" data-type="footer" data-id="3">
    Footer Data
  </div>
  <div class="appName_main" data-type="header" data-id="4">
    Footer Data Two
  </div>

  <div class="appName_main" data-type="offers" data-id="5">
    Offers Data
  </div>
  <div class="appName_main" data-type="offers" data-id="6">
    Offers Data Two
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Menu_list">

  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="header" data-id="1">
    Header One
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="header" data-id="2">
    Header Two
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="footer" data-id="3">
    Footer One
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="footer" data-id="4">
    Footer Two
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="offers" data-id="5">
    Offers One
  </div>
  <div class="appNameSelect" data-type="offers" data-id="6">
    Offers Two
  </div>

</div>

<div id="appendTo">


</div>
```